# Internet Explorer doesn't encode url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-7, internet-explorer-9

Currently developing a web app that sometimes need a specific URL parameter. For example, I am typing this parameter in the URL bar:

```
...Page.aspx?user=chantal.côté
```

Firefox and Chrome will automatically encode the URL like this:

```
...Page.aspx?user=chantal.c%C3%B4t%C3%A9
```

But Internet Explorer doesn't encode automatically the URL, so I get an error with this symbol `�` (when debugging). It all works well when I type `...Page.aspx?user=chantal.c%C3%B4t%C3%A9` but I don't want to do that!

Is there somewhere that I need to explicitly tell Internet Explorer to encode the URL?

Comment: What is the error?  There is probably a better option than finding an IE setting.  You would have to enforce everyone who uses your application to have the same IE settings in this case.

Comment: When I get the data from Request.QueryString["user"].ToString() it gives me � symbols instead of ô or é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your web app doesn't work by getting users to manually type a query string into their browser. Try creating a test HTML page and have the following in it:

```
<a href="http://whatever.com?user=chantal.côté">link</a>
```

Open this test page in IE, and click the link. The characters in the query string will be correctly encoded. It seems that when you manually put stuff in the address bar, IE won't URL-encode it for you, but hopefully this fact is irrelevant to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)
```

Comment: I can't use this because Request.QueryString["user"].ToString() gives me �

Comment: You need to use it on the redirect.  Encode the URL before the request is made and then use UrlDecode(string) on the target page.

Comment: If they're entering this information into a form that is "submitted", you would encode the string OnClick.  There are several event handlers that would allow you to encode the string prior to being submitted.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my point of view. There is no submit on the page. The user manually input the parameter in the URL bar of the browser

Comment: That you cannot control.  That is built-in functionality of IE's address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check out [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) and [HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx) from other side